# choosing encoding and string handling

Tags: c++, c

I am programming some device.
I need to tell encoding to device manufacturer so
that he can create font for device.
My problem is: I am thinking shall I choose UTF8 or UTF16 encoding?

I have checked and most of the letters of my alphabet in 
UTF-8 are 3 bytes.

I am asking this, because which is **easier** to work with, UTF8 or UTF16?
(as I said I am programming on some device, so I am *hesitant* a bit
to install libraries like ICU there and etc.).

Which shall I choose UTF8 or UTF16?

If I take UTF16 - I will have to use `wchar_t` and corresponding functions everywhere right?

Operations I might need on string are: get string length, and do maybe copy of strings.
Maybe also parsing(before I was parsing some data from my string which was written in such form: "param1;param2;param3;")

Comment: Both are Unicode. [Read this](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: @user694733: Hi I've read that but that is not what I asked. I asked which of them is easier to work with (given I am hesitant to install libraries like ICU on device). If I use UTF16 - does it mean I need to use `wchar_t` and corresponding functions everywhere? please look at the question on what I asked.

Comment: Yes you have to unless you want to parse the Unicode file yourself.

Comment: @Abhineet: OK, that in case if I choose UTF16. But what are the benefits if I choose UTF8 in my case? Are there any?

Comment: Both UTF-8 and UTF-16 are variable length encodings, so I don't see much value with UTF-16. (Unless you mean UCS-2 with UTF-16).

Comment: @user694733: I was referring to the one in which each code point is mapped to 16 bit value, I thought UTF16 was about that, or UCS-2? Anyway, the benefit of this I thought was that I could use `wchar_t` type and corresponding functions to handle strings. Whereas if it is UTF-8 and I use plain `char *` I think there are no string methods to operate on strings (unless you use some library like ICU, isn't it?)?

Comment: So you mean UCS-2. [UTF-16 has surrogate pairs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16/UCS-2), which means that single character can be 2 or 4 bytes.

Comment: @user694733: Maybe UCS-2. Btw I checked now and it seems letters of my alphabet map to same values both in UCS2 and UTF16 (that could be the case right?)

Comment: After decoding the UTF-8/UTF-16/UCS-2 letters have same Unicode value. Only difference is that UCS-2 cannot represent all possible letters. I don't *think* your font creator should care about the encoding. He only needs to make sure font is Unicode compatible.

Answer (score 2):

`wchar_t` does not necessarily mean UTF-16. In Linux and Unix (in gcc and clang compiler), `wchar_t` is 4 bytes long which is suitable for UTF-32.

Size of wchar_t depends on compiler.

Unicode data storage should not rely on `wchar`. In C++11, there are types such as `char16_t` and `char32_t`.

Regarding your question which is to be used:

You can perform all of these operations on both UTF-16 and UTF-8.

If space does matter for the characters you have chosen and UTF-16 provides optimal space, then use UTF-16.

However, string comparison is slightly complex in UTF-16 due to involvement of BMP. Which is problematic only if it is going to have characters beyond `U+10000`.

UTF-8 is easier for string comparison, but not for counting number of actual Unicode characters or code points due to variable number of bytes for a code point.

Copy operation has same ease in both of the case.

For parsing, I think separators would be ASCII characters. In this case, both will be easy. If it is non-ASCII, UTF-8 may be slightly difficult to deal with. In this case, UTF-16 will be have problem when there is BMP.

**Thanks user694733 for this.**

UTF-8 representation is same for both little-endian and big-endian but not UTF-16. Here, byte ordering is determined by BOM (Byte order mark).

If you are not planning to use C++11 or C11 for char16_t, then you can store your string in an array of `short` (if it is 16-bits long). But you may end up writing many functions such as string length and string copy on your own (which I think are easy to write except printf and scanf).

Another problem you face in this approach is that you will not be able to declare literals like

```
short word[] = "ABC";
```

which you can gain in C++11.

Comment: Hi Code points for my alphabet are in the form U+xxxx - so I think there is no problem of BMP?? They are less than U+10000 right?? indeed I checked now and sizeof(wchar_t) on this device is 4. Also, I don't plan to use C++ 11

Comment: +1 But you might want to also mention possible endianness issues when loading UTF-16 files.

Comment: @dbasic: and I plan to use `wchar_t` and corresponding functions (e.g., `wcslen`) if I go for UTF16/UCS-2. That's what I should do right? Do you have something against `wchar_t`?

Comment: If sizeof wchar_t is 4 bytes, then how you can go for UTF-16/UCS-2? Storing UTF-16 on wchar_t array in such environment will render wcslen useless.

Comment: @dbasic: I am not sure I understood what you mean, can you elaborate please? explain more

Comment: For example, function wcslen works by counting number of wchar_t in the array. When you store UTF-16 in wchar_t array where each characters take 2 bytes, means either you will store 2 characters per wchar_t or every character in wchar_t. In first case, functions such as wcslen may not work. In second case, you will waste the spaces.

Comment: @dbasic: I just tested wcslen on a string L"HelloWorld" - and it returned 10 correctly. PS. In UTF16 I checked and each letter of my alphabet is represented by two bytes, so which type shall I use to store and manipulate them?

Comment: It will give 10 correctly. But is it internally UTF-16. See memory representation L"HelloWorld" Each character may have taken 4 bytes instead of two.

Comment: @dbasic: So which type shall I use to store/manipulate the utf16 or ucs2 string? Given that all letters of my string are represented as 2 byte values in both UTF16 and UCS2?

Comment: That is why I mentioned `char16_t` type. If you are not going to use C++11, then use unsigned sort. This linke: http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/MELLERY/URL-Google-GURL-0.03/src/googleurl/base/ can help you. See string16.h and string16.cc. This will be of great help to you. Only caveat is that you will not be able to represent literals. For that, you can use some function for encoding conversion.

Comment: @dbasic: hm... thanks I see inside that source code has some functions like strcpy etc for 16 bit version strings right?? I may use smth like u16 ... and then it seems I have to manually implement string handling functions?

Comment: @dbasic: But if I don't care about space then I can store each 2 byte letter in separate `wchar_t` too right? Just in that case I waste space, but then wcslen and such functions will work right?

Comment: Yes. Then they will work.

Comment: @dbasic: Final remark: why I can't use literals? what's the problem there? what do  you mean with literal, like string constants, e.g. "sometext"?

Comment: I meant to say if you use uint16_t or short, then you cannot use literal. For wchar_t, you can. But remember that wchar_t literal stores other thing (UTF-32 character). So, be sure that literals contains only UTF-16 characters.